# Conky, Show Desktop, Swap & Network Meters, Remove Background

Tags: conky

I used conky colors to generate my conky script

**ConkyRC**: http://pastebin.com/cfJ2Zj07

**Output**:

[image]

1. How can I remove the black background?
2. Notice the swap & network meteres does not appear to work?
3. Conky dissapears on using "Show Desktop"

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to define the following properties as follows:

```
own_window yes
own_window_colour 000000    
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type override
```

It will perfectly integrate with your desktop. The only downside is that it will give "static" transparency and therefore hide any underlying desktop icons.

Now if you have a compositor, you can even bypass that little problem using these property values:

```
own_window yes
own_window_argb_visual true
own_window_argb_value 00000000
own_window_colour 000000    
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type normal
```

Answer (score 1):

3: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky#Do_not_minimize_on_Show_Desktop_.28Compiz.29

Lots of other useful info there too!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.